# accessing `http://127.0.0.1:8080/` via wget/curl with powershell encounters "Internet Explorer engine" error, how do I do?

Tags: windows, powershell

I have an http server running well locally.

[image]

I'm trying to access `http://127.0.0.1:8080/` via wget/curl with powershell and get this error

[image]

> The response content cannot be parsed because the Internet Explorer engine is not available

In contrast, git bash works well

[image]

How do I fix the problem and get the HTTP response successfully?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems Internet Explorer is not available on your machine, so the response html can not be parsed by it. You have to tell PowerShell not to use it:

```
curl http://127.0.0.1:8080/ -UseBasicParsing
```

But this means you wont have a DOM object in your response which is sometimes handy.

When using `curl` in Powershell it is just an alias to the `Invoke-WebRequest` cmdlet.

On Linux `curl` uses a completely different binary and behaves differently.